# Does Hisoka conjure cards?

Tags: hunter-x-hunter

It is seen in anime that Hisoka hurls many cards, yet he never runs out of cards.
He was never shown to buy, borrow or steal a deck of cards either.
Moreover, he gets his cards out of nowhere in his hands (he never slips his hands into his pockets or his clothing to fetch cards).

**So does he have the power of conjuring cards?**

Similarly, **does Illumi have the power of conjuring needles, and does Gotoh have the power of conjuring coins?**

Or do they (i.e. Hisoka, Illumi and Gotoh) belong to the category of **Emmiter**?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those are real Cards, Coins and Needles.

Chalk it up to Anime trope that he doesn't run out of Cards. Also its a logical fallacy to assume Hisoka doesn't buy/borrow/steal cards since its not shown. The seemingly cards out of nowhere is a nod to the "Magician" theme of Hisoka.

Hisoka carries with him a normal Deck of cards and uses Nen (Shu(?)) to make it razor sharp enough to kill. Similarly Gotoh and Illumi can use Nen to fashion deadly projectiles.

One of the examples I can use here is that of Gotoh vs Hisoka fight.

> Hisoka was able to fire back the coins used by Gotoh, if they were conjured he would've simple "unconjured" them instead of shooting them down. This I think proves the coins were real

This is a common trope in many Anime or Manga where the characters have seemingly endless supplies of "anything" they may need. Kunai and Shuriken in Naruto never seem to run out, Duelists in Yu-Gi-Oh never run out of cards etc.

Comment: *"Duelists in Yu-Gi-Oh never run out of cards"* except when Yugi was fighting that Rare Hunter Marik was controlling, the only way he won was to use Marik's strategy in making Slifer the Sky Dragon powerful was making it enter an endless loop in which Marik's Rare Hunter ended up drawing every card from his deck (which the rules state that if you have no cards to draw you loose the match)

Comment: @Memor-X Despite several subversions of the trope for reasons of plot, it is a common trope. I made a generic statement. Taking the example of Naruto again. Shikamaru had a limit on the number of Ninja Tools he had against Tayuya while he seemingly had unlimited against Hidan. I am sure there are instances where Yugi fought "very" long fights without running out of cards.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, He was shown to conjure his bungee gum with coins attached to it, Also cards don’t kill people and those are obviously not metal so that was a hint of shu existing.